# Make pg_createcluster create the config dir even though the data dir exists

Tags: postgresql

We have an Ansible playbook that sets up PostgreSQL 15. It creates a new cluster using `pg_createcluster`, makes some changes to the config files that `pg_createcluster` creates (in /etc/postgresql/15/...), etc. This works fine when the PG cluster is new, but sometimes we want to reinstall the OS while keeping the PG data (which is on separate disks). Then pg_createcluster fails with:

> Configuring already existing cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/15/...
>
> Error: move_conffile: required configuration file DATA_DIR/postgresql.conf does not exist

This limitation is documented on the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html):

> If the data directory already exists, it is integrated into the postgresql-common structure by moving the configuration file and setting the data_directory option. Please note that this only works for data directories which were created directly with initdb, i.  e. all the configuration files (postgresql.conf etc.) must be present in the data directory.

OK, but... what are we supposed to do when the cluster was created using `pg_createcluster`? Seems like that would be a common scenario that should be supported!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to check if the data directory already exists (and contains a PG_VERSION file, to be sure) and, if so, run `pg_createcluster --datadir=SOME_TEMP_DIR` where `SOME_TEMP_DIR` is just a random temporary directory, then update `data_directory` in `postgresql.conf` to the real one (using the Ansible `lineinfile` module) and delete `SOME_TEMP_DIR`.